# Sending multiple files from HTML Input from Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, dropzone.js, htmlunit

Working with HtmlUnit and Java I am trying to send some files through this element:

```html
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" class="dz-hidden-input" accept="image/jpeg, image/gif ,image/png" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
```

It comes from Dropzone javascript library wchich creates this hidden HTML element in order to manage files uploading.

I have tried (among other things) this one:

```java
File fileToUpload = new File("C:\\image.jpg");
HtmlFileInput fileUploader = (HtmlFileInput) currentPage.getFirstByXPath("//input[@type='file']");

fileUploader.setFiles(fileToUpload);
```

But it fails miserably with this exception which makes me sure this is not the way to proceed, any hints?

```
    GRAVE: Job run failed with unexpected RuntimeException: TypeError: Cannot find function readAsDataURL in object [object FileReader]. (https://static.milanuncios.com/js/fotos/dropzone.4.2.0.min.js#1)
    ======= EXCEPTION START ========
    EcmaError: lineNumber=[1] column=[0] lineSource=[  function () {] name=
    [TypeError] sourceName=
    [https://static.milanuncios.com/js/fotos/dropzone.4.2.0.min.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot find function readAsDataURL in object [object FileReader]. (https://static.milanuncios.com/js/fotos/dropzone.4.2.0.min.js#1)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function readAsDataURL in object [object FileReader]. (https://static.milanuncios.com/js/fotos/dropzone.4.2.0.min.js#1)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:894)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:637)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:518)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:823)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:795)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2504)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2497)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptFunctionJob.runJavaScript(JavaScriptFunctionJob.java:52)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptExecutionJob.run(JavaScriptExecutionJob.java:102)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.runSingleJob(JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.java:424)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.run(DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.java:155)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function readAsDataURL in object [object FileReader]. (https://static.milanuncios.com/js/fotos/dropzone.4.2.0.min.js#1)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3915)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3899)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3924)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3940)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:4007)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2402)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2384)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1348)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:416)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:322)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:816)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:879)
    ... 11 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function readAsDataURL in object [object FileReader]. (https://static.milanuncios.com/js/fotos/dropzone.4.2.0.min.js#1)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3915)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3899)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3924)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3940)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:4007)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2402)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2384)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1348)
    at script(https://static.milanuncios.com/js/fotos/dropzone.4.2.0.min.js:1)
    at script(https://static.milanuncios.com/js/fotos/dropzone.4.2.0.min.js:1)
    at script(https://static.milanuncios.com/js/fotos/dropzone.4.2.0.min.js:1)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:416)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:322)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:816)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:879)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:637)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:518)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:823)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:795)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2504)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2497)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptFunctionJob.runJavaScript(JavaScriptFunctionJob.java:52)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptExecutionJob.run(JavaScriptExecutionJob.java:102)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.runSingleJob(JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.java:424)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.run(DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.java:155)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==
  function () {
      return a._processThumbnailQueue();
  }
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an [Issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1912/) open for that. Work on this has already started. Please check the issue for progress.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting, it has been implemented in SVN.

You can use [latest build](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts) or maven snapshot.